# Order data depending on multiple range criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to order data using multiple ranges. Let's suppose I have some data in tt array:

```
n= 50
b = 20
r = 3
tt = np.array([[[3]*r]*b]*n)
```

and another values in list:

```
z = (np.arange(0,5,0.1)).tolist()
```

Now I need to sort data from tt depending on ranges from z, which should go between 0 and 1, next range is between 1 and 2, next one between 2 and 3 and so on.
My attempts by now were trying to create array of length of each of ranges, and use those length to cut data from tt. Looks something like this:

```
za = []
za2 = []
za3 = []
za4 = []
za5 = []
za6 = []
za7 = []
for y in range(50):
    if 0 <= int(z[y]) < 1:
        za.append(z[y])
        zi = array([int(len(za))])
    if 1 <= int(z[y]) < 2:
        za2.append(z[y])
        zi2 = array([int(len(za2))])
    if 2 <= int(z[y]) < 3:
        za3.append(z[y])
        zi3 = array([int(len(za3))])
    if 3 <= int(z[y]) < 4:
        za4.append(z[y])
        zi4 = array([int(len(za4))])
    if 4 <= int(z[y]) < 5:
        za5.append(z[y])
        zi5 = array([int(len(za5))])
    if 5 <= int(z[y]) < 6:
        za6.append(z[y])
        zi6 = array([int(len(za6))])
    if 6 <= int(z[y]) < 7:
        za7.append(z[y])
        zi7 = array([int(len(za7))])
till = np.concatenate((np.array(zi), np.array(zi2), np.array(zi3), np.array(zi4), np.array(zi5), np.array(zi6), np.array(zi7))

ttn = []
for p in range(50):
    #if hour_lenght[p] != []
    tt_h = np.empty(shape(tt[0:till[p],:,:]))
    tt_h[:] = np.nan
    tt_h = tt_h[np.newaxis,:,:,:]
    tt_h[np.newaxis,:,:,:] = tt[0:till[p],:,:]
    ttn.append(tt_h)
```

As you can guess,I get an error "name 'zi6' is not defined" since there are no data in that range. But at least it does the job for the parts that do exist :D. However, if I include **else** statement after **if** and do something like:

```
for y in range(50):
    if 0 <= int(z[y]) < 1:
        za.append(z[y])
        zi = np.array([int(len(za))])
    else:
        zi = np.array([np.nan])
```

My initial zi from 1st part gets overwritten with nan.

I should also point that the ultimate goal is to load multiple files that are having similar shape as tt (two last dimensions are always the same while the first one is changing,  e.g. :

```
tt.shape 
(50, 20, 3)
```

and some other tt2 is having shape:

```
tt2.shape
(55, 20, 3)
```

with z2 that is having values between 5 and 9.

```
z2 = (np.arange(5,9,0.1)).tolist()
```

So in the end I should end up with array ttn wheres

ttn[0] is filled with values from tt in range between 0 and 1,

ttn[1] should be filled with values from tt in between 1 and 2 and so on.

I very much appreciate suggestions and possible solutions on this issue.